# How to authenticate request with OpenID from JMeter as it throws 401 Un-Authorized error

Tags: openid

How to authenticate request with OpenID from JMeter as it throws 401 Un-Authorized error:
Response code: 401
Response message: Unauthorized

I am using BlazeMeter to record the request and the same JMX is using in JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not personally familiar with OpenID, but I can say that in my experience, most 401 errors are due to not having setup authentication tokens properly in the script.

If you used the BlazeMeter Chrome Extension to create your script, this is probably the problem, because the recorder is unable to automatically script token-handling; that always requires manual intervention.

We've got a guide with a couple of demo videos of how to setup authentication tokens in your script -- you may find it helpful:
https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421705